# Python statement: sometimes True, sometimes False. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean, behavior

I wanted to get a better understanding of OOP in Python and wrote a bit of code describing (infinite) ordinal arithmetic. I defined a class named `Omega()` with the usual comparison operators (`==`, `<=`, etc.), addition and multiplication.

I thought I'd check whether (as should be true) the first infinite ordinal added to itself was less-than-or-equal-to the first uncountable ordinal. Launching the interactive shell, here's what I found:

```
    >>> a, b = Omega(), Omega(1)
    >>> (a+a) <= b
    False
    >>> (a+a) <= b
    True
    >>> (a+a) <= b
    False
```

The same expression produces different truth values.

I continued to test the expression and could not spot any pattern. If I re-interpret the code, I find that repeatedly testing the expression produces a different sequence of `True`/`False` values.

What could be causing this behaviour?

If it's relevant, I'm using CPython 2.7.5 on Windows 8.1.

Here's the Python code I ran: http://pastebin.com/XPqMphBw

Comment: @SethMMorton No, I'm not importing any modules.

Comment: Sounds like you need to throw in some `print` statements in your methods to see what values the variables actually contain each time you do the comparison.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham - Fair enough, it could be an issue with my system rather than what I've written.

Comment: In your code, `index` and `copies` sometimes appear to be integers, other times instances of `Omega`. It's not clear how your implementation works.

Comment: *Can* replicate. No idea what's going on but I don't want other people to ignore it based on that comment. Printing `(a+a) <= b, (a+a).__dict__, b.__dict__` shows no difference in the dicts between True and False results.

Agree that the types of copies,index,power are confusing. All the comparison code expects them to be Omegas, but all the assignments are to ints.

Comment: @Mark, chepner - thanks, it really intended as a first draft of an idea rather than a well-thought out piece of code. I expected only one truth value though, however confusing the code may be!

Comment: I can replicate using `(a+a)` then calling `(a+a) <= b` but never just calling `(a+a) <= b`, I am using ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.8. I imagine your issue is windows specific

Comment: Replicated on OSX Mavericks with 2.7.5. I can't imagine how on earth something like that would be Windows specific.

Comment: FYI, pastebin.com is full of ads for anyone not running Adblock or an equivalent. Please use an ad-free pastebin (http://gist.github.com/ is widely accepted; http://ix.io/ or http://sprunge.us/ also good and trivially postable from the command line with nothing but curl) in the future.

Comment: @Charles - apologies, I'll use an alternative in future.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield, you might need a better imagination then, there are plenty issues in python that are windoze specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you overloaded the `<=` and `>=` operators incorrectly. Instead of:

```
def __leq__(self, other):
# ...
def __geq__(self, other):
```

use this instead:

```
def __le__(self, other):
# ...
def __ge__(self, other):
```

After making these changes and running this in Python 3.4.1, I get:

```
>>> a, b = Omega(), Omega(1)
>>> (a+a) <= b
True
>>> (a+a) <= b
True
>>> (a+a) <= b
True
```

Comment: Ah! I've just tried this modification and it seems to work. Thanks! Any idea of the reason behind the unpredictable truth value before though?

Comment: No idea unfortunately. I couldn't reproduce your error; instead, I would get: `TypeError: unorderable types: Omega() <= Omega()`.

Comment: A speculation. Since `__geq__` is not a special name, you actually _did not_ define a comparison operator. Python 2.x returns random garbage based on object identity in this case; you generated new transient objects by calculating `a+a`, and some of them "compared" to `b` differently. Python 3.x in absence of ordering operator clearly says 'type <whatever> is unorderable'.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Padraic Cunningham, I also cannot replicate your problem (under Python 2.7.5 on Mac OS X). It gives me consistent answers.

You would do well to give your objects a comprehensible `__repr__` method so that they are easily printed for debugging purposes. For example:

```
def __repr__(self):
    innards = ", ".join(str(v) for v in [self.index, self.power, self.copies])
    return "{0}({1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, innards)
```

Printing `a` would then show `Omega(0, 1, 1)`. A slightly fancier version might be:

```
def __repr__(self):
    innards = "index={index}, power={power}, copies={copies}".format(**self.__dict__)
    return "{0}({1})".format(self.__class__.__name__, innards)
```

I also note that your code is probably not computing "less than or equal" the way you think it is. You have methods `__leq__` and `__geq__` defined, but those are not part of the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). You want (and need) `__le__` and `__ge__` instead. If those are not defined, a combination of `__eq__` and  `__lt__` are called instead. That combination generally has logical equivalency, if you're using a standard algebraic definition of `<=`, but in this case... It's at least a place to check.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using `__le__` and `__ge__` now and it appears to be giving consistent values. I did have a `__repr__` method (I must have cut it out by mistake when I pasted to PasteBin) to print out LaTeX representations of `Omega()`. I think I had `<=` muddled with the LaTeX `\leq`...